# Default destructor for pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, destructor

Suppose I have a self-defined vector class and the destructor for the vector class is defined as below,

```
 ~vector(void) {
        for (uint64_t i = 0; i<len_elem; i++) { //destruct each elem
                front[i].~T();
        }
        ::operator delete(head);
        head = nullptr;
        capacity = 0;
 }
```

In my understanding, this destructor works fine for most cases. However if the vector is `vector<vector*> myVec`, will the code in the destructor execute correctly? To be specific, will the `front[i].~T();` correctly invoke the the destructor of vector class?

Comment: In a word: no.  As to whether that's "correct" or not, it depends on the use-case.

Comment: Pointers do not have destructors, but you can call a destructor on an object via a pointer (using the `delete` operator).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## TLDR: Your code is fine.

Long answer: Yes and no.

`front[i].~T()` will "correctly call the destructor for a pointer*".  However, a pointer's "destructor" does nothing at all.  So this code *correctly* does nothing.

If you wanted to *free* the things the pointers point at, that's an altogether different thing.  The easiest thing to do in this case is to instead use `vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>` or whatever, so that this destructor will call the destructors of the `unique_ptr`, and *those* destructors free the memory.

As a note, virtually every sequential container tries to destroy elements from back to front instead of the way you have it.  Some classes can be a touch picky about the construction/destruction order.

<sup>* Built in types don't *technically* have members like destructors, but you can pretend they do for all intents and purposes except that you can't reference them by name.</sup>

Comment: The standard sequential containers don't specify destruction order (that I know of), so any such "picky class" would be a buggy class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and I am curious about the reason the container would better destroy elements from back to front. Would you mind to share , or a link may help.

Comment: @elexonics: It is a widely accepted convention that destruction order should be the exact reverse of construction order. This convention is strictly followed by C++ language with regard to local objects, static objects, class members, raw arrays etc. For this reason it might make sense to stick to that convention with your containers as well. However, `std::vector` apparently does not guarantee that.